# How are category theory and probability theory related?

Tags: probability, category-theory, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian

How are category theory and probability theory related ? Category theory seems very useful for understanding objects with definite relationships, whereas probability theory (particular Bayesian methods), can be applied to areas where there is uncertainty. My question is, what attempts have been made to combine these disciplines ? Are there areas of category theory which focus upon probabilistic situations ? Have there been approaches using Bayesian methods etc. to build category theoretic representations of data ? Are there applications of category theory to probabilistic programming ?

Comment: Maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6030 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical help.

Comment: Also related: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/09/a_categorical_look_at_random_v.html

Comment: Category-theoretic approaches to probability are a very active area of research at the moment. I particularly like Tobias Fritz' work on [Markov categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07021) as a framework. There's a very nice, but unordered, list of papers [here](https://ncatlab.org/davidcorfield/show/probability#references), including several other approaches.

Comment: The giry monad comes to mind

Comment: I know this question is a predecessor to your [What is a good category for probability theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153864/what-is-a-good-category-for-probability-theory) question, but I just wanted to highlight the incredible work by [Tuyéras (2020)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.09999.pdf) on statistical testing and inference. Here is a [YouTube walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbXUB-rbqpw) by the author. PS: I only recently found out about the Topos Institute and wish I knew about it earlier.