# What is a good category for probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am searching for a good category to think about probability theory in, with arrows as something like stochastic maps. There are certain nice structural features I would like the category to have (listed below) and I was hoping somebody could tell me if there are any categories meeting a lot of these conditions:

1. A monoidal category with a tensor product corresponding to something like the Cartesian product. Actually it would be good if it was a Markov category (like $\text{FinStoch}$ is for example).
2. In addition to having objects corresponding to finite sets/spaces it would be good to have infinite sets/spaces appearing as objects. Ideally I want to be able to talk about continuous probability distributions (using real numbers etc.) in addition to discrete probability distributions.
3. It would be great if I can form disjoint unions or coproducts of objects. Ideally I would like the category to be a bimonoidal category / rig category with $ \otimes $ corresponding to the Cartesian product and $\oplus$ corresponding to the disjoint union.
4. It would be great if the deterministic maps/functions from something like Set are included in the category too, so I can think about functional programming and recursion there too.

I realize I am asking for a lot, but there are many different categories for doing probability theory which are mentioned in the literature, so I was hoping somebody could highlight some categories which get close to fulfilling my conditions. In particular there seem to be many categories such as $\text{FinStoch}$, $\text{Stoch}$, $\text{CGStoch}$ and $\text{BorelStoch}$ defined by [Fong](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6201) and [Fritz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07021). Also 28:38 of [Perrone's YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3Da88Tgw_rM) defines more categories (like the category of finitary stochastic maps, which is the Kleisli category of Set using the distribution monad, and may meet some of my conditions).

Comment: Yes, $\sf FinStoch$ is good starting point. In particular with the continuous nature of the objects we can think about the co-Kleisli category ${\sf CoKl}$ equipped with $(A\otimes\_)$. In some works it is termed $\sf CEuc$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by the co-Kleiski category $\text{CoKl},$ do you have any links to literature about it etc., so I can find a definition ?

Comment: See, for instance [Shiebler (2021)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.04735.pdf) for a very recent development around this area.

Comment: That looks like a great paper. Also, I wonder if $\text{FinStoch}$ is a rig category in the sense of my condition (3) above

Comment: I'm not sure. With $\sf FinStoch$ (or $\sf Stoch$ in general) we have $\otimes$ as the Cartesian/Kronecker product but I don't know about $\oplus$.

Comment: Yea, I guess I will have to calculate. I'm thinking it does have an initial object, but there seems to be some conflicting literature about that, as I asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4148406/does-the-category-of-finite-stochastic-maps-hold-the-empty-set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting question as there are a few perspectives we can take. In this answer, I'll provide some insight in the stochastic and causal cases. Whilst I am unaware of a category that meets all four criteria, there do exist categories that meet at least two of them.

From a stochastic perspective, the category $\sf FinStoch$ is a good starting point because it is the category of Markov kernels between finite sets so **Criterion 1.** is met. However it is only mostly used in the discrete case; for instance, in information theory/Bayesian networks, it can be applied in the formulation of the discrete (Shannon) entropy and divergence criteria. The Master's theses [Fong (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6201.pdf) and [Rischel (2020)](https://www.erischel.com/documents/mscthesis.pdf) are also quite helpful.

More recently, [Shiebler (2021)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.04735.pdf) discovered a connection between categorical models and maximum likelihood estimation, developing from Fong (2012). This used the co-Kleisli category $\sf CoKl$ under the co-monad $(A\otimes\_)$ where $A$ is an object in the Cartesian monoidal category $C$. In the special case of the real space $\Bbb R^n$, this is termed $\sf CEuc$. This answers to **Criterion 1.** and **Criterion 2.** as the setting is wholly continuous.

As a bonus to **Criterion 1.**, the related category $\sf PEuc$ (allowing stochastic processes in more than one probability space) was shown to be extendable to a Markov category. This is shown in Proposition 5, where each object is equipped with the comultiplication map $cp$ and the counit map $dc$ such that \begin{align}cp:1\times\Bbb R^a\to\Bbb R^a\times\Bbb R^a\quad&\text{where}\quad cp(-,x_a)=(x_a,x_a)\\dc:1\times\Bbb R^a\to1\quad&\text{where}\quad dc(-,x_a)=-.\end{align}

To give a reasonably close answer to **Criterion 3.**, we can link the areas of stochastic theory and metric spaces together. The Kantorovich monad comes into mind, and the details are provided in the PhD thesis by [Perrone (2018)](http://www.paoloperrone.org/phdthesis.pdf). By equipping the category (derived from $\sf 
CMet$, the category of complete metric spaces) with both lax morphisms (convex maps) and oplax morphisms (concave maps), it is possible to construct a hexagon equation to show bimonoidality. This is given in Proposition 2.5.16. Note **Criterion 2.** is also satisfied.

I don't know of a useful category that obeys **Criterion 4.** and at least one other criterion. In terms of recursion though, it could be worthwhile to study the backpropagation functor through $\sf Learn$ as each set of morphisms in the learning algorithm may be transferrable to models involving Bayesian updating, given a well-defined initial state.

With this literature being discussed, I think the Markov extension of $\sf PEuc$ would be of most relevance to the question and hopefully Shiebler's work will be further developed in the near future.